# Spring REST LocalDate UTC differs of one day

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-data-rest

I'm using Spring Boot 1.5.4, Hibernate 5.2.10, Spring Data REST, HATEOAS, JDK8 with LocalDate and LocalDateTime.
My computer is on CEST timezone but I want the application works in UTC, so I set in application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database?useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useSSL=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone = UTC
```

According to this [article](https://moelholm.com/2016/11/09/spring-boot-controlling-timezones-with-hibernate/) I don't want to change the timezone of my JVM because seems not to be a best practice.

Spring Data REST exposes my repositories and I use Swagger2 to have a nice interface to use API.
When I try a endpoint I see something like:

```
    {
  "_embedded": {
    "dailyCodes": [
      {
        "sid": "d495cdaa-14f2-44cb-a98f-8aa6ddd43d91",
        "createdDate": "2017-06-28T16:20:01",
        "lastModifiedDate": "2017-06-28T16:20:01",
        "lastModifiedBy": "admin",
        "date": "2017-06-28",
        "code": "js",
        "new": false,
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/dailyCodes/1"
          },
          "dailyCode": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/dailyCodes/1"
          }
        }
      }
```

Like you can see the datetime format is fine and also it display the CEST time even if in the db the real time is 14:20:01.
I guess this is wrong because my REST API should work in UTC.

How could I achieve this result?

Always on the same topic, I've a REST endpoint (exposed by Spring Data REST) to search using LocalDate params; I'm using

```
@Transactional
@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
public interface DailyCodeRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<DailyCode, Long> {

@Query("SELECT d FROM DailyCode d WHERE (:code IS NULL or code=:code) AND (:from IS NULL OR date>=:from) AND (:to IS NULL OR date<=:to)")
    public Page<DailyCode> findAllWithParameter(@Param("code") @RequestParam(value = "code", required = false) String code,
            @Param("from") @RequestParam(value = "from", required = false) LocalDate from,
            @Param("to") @RequestParam(value = "to", required = false) LocalDate to, Pageable pageable);
}
```

Also in this case I've a strange thing: if I call the endpoint passing parameters, in the server they arrive with 1 day less. Furthemore the  date pattern accepted seems to be the JDK default of my locale (Italian) but I guess it's not a best practice.

Is there a best practice to follow to avoid any problems with date/time arguments in both direction?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with LocalDate and such. However, the 

    jdbc.time_zone 

parameter only affects the conversion between inside the VM and the database. In the JDBC driver, there will be a Date object, which is basically era milliseconds without any timezone information. usually, when this is formatted as a (human readable) string, this would be done according to the timezone specified in the formatter OR the default timezone.

Comment: however, when it is formatted to be written to the database as a date, the jdbc.time_zone parameter is used for this conversion. i am not sure what happens when that Date object is converted to a LocalDate, but i am assuming that the problem you have lies there, rather  than in the conversion between VM and DB.

Answer (score 6):

I agree with the author of this article [The 5 laws of API dates and times](http://apiux.com/2013/03/20/5-laws-api-dates-and-times/) that we have to store and return time in UTC. And 'front-end' must decide itself how to convert the time value depending on the client time-zone.

To achieve this (store and return time in UTC) we set JVM parameter `-Duser.timezone=UTC` or add `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone=UTC` to `application.properties` (starting from Hibernate 5.2.3.Final). Then change time fields of our entities from `LocalDateTime` (that doesn't store time-zone info) to `ZonedDateTime` type.

After that the time values will be stored in UTC independently from the local time-zone of the computer where the application is started and SDR will return these values in **ISO8601** form: **`2017-07-02T11:58:10.089Z`**

But if it's necessary to return time values in the specific time-zone we have to setup @JsonFormat annotation to all of our time fields:

```
@JsonFormat(timezone = "Europe/Rome", pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
private ZonedDateTime createdDate;
```

Our we can define constant `TIME_ZONE` in our application and set it in @JsonFormat annotations: `@JsonFormat(timezone = Application.TIME_ZONE, ...)`.

Then we get this output:

```
{
    //...
    "createdDate": "2017-07-02T14:11:45.964+0200",
    //...
}
```

Unfortunately, parameter `spring.jackson.time-zone` (based on my short investigation) affects only on service messages in the application, for example:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2017-07-02T14:14:09.486+0200",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/users"
}
```

To get time here in 'zoned' form we have to set properly `spring.jackson.date-format` parameter in the `application.properties`:

```
spring.jackson.date-format=com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.StdDateFormat
```

Comment: I'm absolutely sure. In the DB the time is in UTC, but when I return the value using Spring REST the date is in my local time zone.

Comment: I'm about that: `spring.jpa.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone = UTC` in your question. In my answer I suggest to use another option: 'spring.jackson.time-zone'

Comment: Yes I'm sure. This is a portion on my properties file: #Jackson
spring.jackson.mapper.infer-property-mutators=false
spring.jackson.time-zone=UTC

Comment: Are your JDK in a different timezone from UTC? Are you storing date in UTC format in the db?

Comment: @drenda It doesn't matter now... I was misled by the time value in an error message. See my answer I updated it...

Comment: congratulation for the reply.Using ZonedDateTime in combination with @JsonFormat(timezone = "UTC", pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ") I've UTC reply in REST response. I'm wondering if there is a way to avoid use ZonedDateTime as entity field, or at least set a global JsonFormat. I've to set the annotation on all beans! Thanks