# Data type of time in Spring-Data-Rest

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-data-rest, sqldatatypes

I want to store the time what data type should I used in spring framework ? 
Database which I used is MySQL

```
@Entity
public class ShopDetail {

@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private String address;

    private Double latitude;

    private Double longitude;

    private float  rating;

    private Time openingTime;

    private Time closingTime;
    }
```

Comment: Either java.util.date or java.sql.date

Comment: The [@Temporal](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Temporal.html) annotation is used to specify the TemporalType of the current annotated java.util.Date or java.util.Calendar entity attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Java 8, the most business logic, entity fields may be using [Instant](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) - basic class in `java.time` API for representing a moment in the timeline in UTC.

If you need timezone data, you may consider using:

> [ZonedDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) is an immutable representation of a date-time with a time-zone. This
>   class stores all date and time fields

Another option [LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html):

> A date-time without a time-zone in the ISO-8601 calendar system, such
>   as 2007-12-03T10:15:30

But then you would rely on a default system timezone which may bring contradicting results if a system timezone would change.

Check [Java 8: What's the difference between Instant and LocalDateTime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32437550/java-8-whats-the-difference-between-instant-and-localdatetime) or [Hibernate with Java 8 LocalDate & LocalDateTime in Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43476364/hibernate-with-java-8-localdate-localdatetime-in-database/44715566#44715566) for explicit explanation.

Answer (score 0):

you can use date time format.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/annotation/DateTimeFormat.html

[Spring 3.2 Date time format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17754849/spring-3-2-date-time-format)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java 8 time types in your entities. Just add this dependencies to your projects:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-java8</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

According to this article [The 5 laws of API dates and times](http://apiux.com/2013/03/20/5-laws-api-dates-and-times/) I'd recommend to use `ZonedDateTime` in REST projects.

Also pay attention to this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44830861)...